# Spring boot kotlin project cannot load java classes on the run time

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, kotlin

I'm using spring boot 2.0 in kotlin programming language. In my project I use Java classes as well as Kotlin classes but when I build  project using gradle and running on the terminal the following command

```
java -jar my_springboot_kotlin_gradle_project
```

& I'm getting an error like this

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.example.components.utils.EncryptionUtils    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) 
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_171] 
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClas
>   sLoader.java:93) ~[myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_171] 
>   ... 15 common frames omitted

and If I use java spring beans in the kotlin spring beans spring boot cannot autowire java beans.

Answer (score 0):

It will be good if you post tour `gradle` file. Even though this is my observation, you need to add class path into application jar while creating / building using `maven or gradle`. This is called **Fat JAR.**

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.test.example.MainKt' // add your main class path
    }

   // check this line / task properly
   from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

For more detailed info, you can refer this [Medium](https://medium.com/@preslavrachev/kotlin-basics-create-executable-kotlin-jars-using-gradle-d17e9a8384b9) link.